# Calculating Edge Percentage using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have some NCLD data of an area I've clipped out and there is a count of each habitat class (open water, deciduous forest, etc.).

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the edge amount of these habitat classes in ArcGIS 10.6.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: You could [polygonize the raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) by class then calculate the perimeter for each

Comment: I'm able to convert the raster to a polygon but I'm unsure of how to carry the existing symbology/classes with it. After conversion it seems to just have a single category it sorts everything into.

I think I need to change the category to unique values but I'm not sure how to get what was there before the conversion.

Comment: Whatever you specify as the `raster_field` should hold the cell value, so you should be able to symbolize based on that